# Scenekit Imported cube with 16x16 textures laggy on device

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit

I created a very quick cube in blender and added simple 16x16 textures in the UV. I then created a scene.scnassets folder with the cube and image. I loaded in the model into Scenekit and ran it on my iPhone 5. The fps got down to 44 when I use the camera controls. It should be at 60 like the demo project. It has no lights and way less faces than the default ship. Does anyone know why this is happening? Here is the download to my project for testing:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/6g0thad00sdvsdv/SceneKit_game.zip

I am not running it in the simulator

Why is my project lagging so much?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I found the answer. For anyone wondering, scene kit updates framerate only when it needs to. When something does not need to be displayed at 60 fps (like the camera staying still), the scene will not update the framerate. It is still actually running at 60 fps but only when it needs to.